# Android Studio :- Your build is currently configured to use Java 19.0.2 and Gradle 7.5

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 19.0.2 and Gradle 7.5.

Possible solution:

- Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXiFY.png)

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently Gradle 7.5 doesn't support Java 19](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20372). That fix went into Gradle 7.6.

So open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
```

Changing 7.5 to 7.6.

Android studio will download the updated Gradle and then you can resync and shouldn't have any errors.  Worked for me at least, hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally did it in Android Studio Flamingo with Java Version 8 Update 371 that was released in April 2023:

In gradle-wrapper.properties change the distribution URL to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip

You might get an error with 3 possible fixes suggested. Just click on the link 'update wrapper and reimport project'

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Download and install Java version `19.0.2` from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk19-archive-downloads.html).

Then go to `Gradle/Wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` from your root project and set the `distributionUrl` property to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip`.

Next, sync your Gradle project in Android Studio.